# Httprio Delphi version XE - XE5 - XE7. calling a Webservice in Basic authentication with a certificate

Tags: web-services, delphi, ssl, certificate

Hi everyone and sorry for my poor english.

I have a problem to query a webservice that requires a certificate in Basic Authentication. This is the code that I created

```
procedure Tmenu.btnConverterClick (Sender: TObject);
var
  _ccSoap: VisualizzaErogatoRicevuta;
  _rio: THTTPRIO;
  ParametridaPassare: VisualizzaErogatoRichiesta;
  myservice: visualizzaErogatoPT;
begin
  _rio: = THTTPRIO.Create (Self);
  _rio.OnBeforeExecute: = Self.httpRioBeforeExecute;
  _rio.OnAfterExecute: = Self.httpRioAfterExecute;
  _rio.HTTPWebNode.OnBeforePost: = Self.HTTPRIOHTTPWebNode1BeforePost;
 _rio.URL:='https://demservicetest.sanita.finanze.it/DemRicettaErogatoServicesWeb/services/demVisualizzaErogato';
  ParametridaPassare: = VisualizzaErogatoRichiesta.Create;
  _ccSoap: = VisualizzaErogatoRicevuta.Create;

  ParametridaPassare.pinCode: = 'xxxx';
  ParametridaPassare.codiceRegioneErogatore: = '222';
  ParametridaPassare.codiceAslErogatore: = '299';
  ParametridaPassare.codiceSsaErogatore: = '33333338';
  ParametridaPassare.nre: = '190345435345';
  ParametridaPassare.tipoOperazione: = '1';
  myservice: = _ rio as visualizzaErogatoPT;
  _ccSoap: = myservice.visualizzaErogato (ParametridaPassare);
  try
    ShowMessage (_ccsoap.cognNome);
    ShowMessage (_ccsoap.codiceAss);
    ShowMessage (_ccsoap.cfMedico1);
    ShowMessage (_ccsoap.cfMedico2);
    ShowMessage (_ccsoap.descrizioneDiagnosi);
    ShowMessage (_ccsoap.nre);
  finally
    _ccSoap: = nil;
  end;
end;



procedure TMenu.HTTPRIOHTTPWebNode1BeforePost (const HTTPReqResp: THTTPReqResp;  Data: Pointer);
Const
  INTERNET_OPTION_CLIENT_CERT_CONTEXT = 84;
var
  Store        : IStore;
  Certs        : ICertificates;
  Cert         : ICertificate2;
  CertContext  : ICertContext;
  PCertContext : PCCERT_CONTEXT;
  V            : OleVariant;
  SS,S            : String;
  CertificateFilename: PWideChar;
  Certificate: ICertificate2;
  Password: String;
  i : integer;
  UserName: string;
begin
  V := '6C791E67ACD205940DB36444BDB5C81FD89A2214';
  Store := CoStore.Create;
  (* open the My Store containing certs with private keys *)
  Store.Open( CAPICOM_CURRENT_USER_STORE, 'MY', CAPICOM_STORE_OPEN_MAXIMUM_ALLOWED );
  Certs := Store.Certificates;
  for i := 1 to certs.Count do
    begin
      cert := IInterface(Certs.Item[i]) as ICertificate2;
      ss:=cert.SubjectName;
      if cert.Thumbprint=V then
        begin
          CertContext := Cert as ICertContext;
          CertContext.Get_CertContext( Integer( PCertContext ) );
          HTTPReqResp.ClientCertificate.CertName:=cert.SubjectName;
          HTTPReqResp.ClientCertificate.Issuer:=cert.IssuerName;
          HTTPReqResp.ClientCertificate.SerialNum:=cert.SerialNumber;
        if InternetSetOption( Data, INTERNET_OPTION_CLIENT_CERT_CONTEXT, PCertContext, Sizeof( CERT_CONTEXT ) ) = False then
    begin
      ShowMessage( 'Problema no certificado!!!!!!!!!!' );
    end;
 end 
end;


procedure TMenu.httpRioAfterExecute(const MethodName: string;
  SOAPResponse: TStream);
begin
  SOAPResponse.Position := 0;
  mmResponse.Lines.LoadFromStream(SOAPResponse);
  SOAPResponse.Position := 0;
end;

procedure TMenu.httpRioBeforeExecute(const MethodName: string;
  SOAPRequest: TStream);
begin
  SOAPRequest.Position := 0;
  mmRequest.Lines.LoadFromStream(SOAPRequest);
  SOAPRequest.Position := 0;
end;
```

It seems that the certificate is loaded correctly. What are the instructions and where do I put them to query the webservice in basic authentication through username and password in BASE64?

Thank you all for the help.

Comment: Is there an error message? What exactly is the problem, what response does the server send?

Comment: You can set the username and password via `_rio.HTTPWebNode`